# selecting the first element value from the list returned by criteria

Tags: hibernate, criteria

I have criteria which is finally returing a list as shown below..

```
ment = (Iils) criteria.uniqueResult();
```

but please advise how can I do the necessary changes as i want to retrieve the first item from the list  and not the unique result please advise what changes i need to do to achieve that

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `setFirstResult()` and `setMaxResults()` method in `Criteria`. Here is an [example](http://www.developerhelpway.com/framework/hibernate/hibernate-pagination-claus.php)

```
criteria.setFirstResult(0);
criteria.setMaxResults(1);
```